# Which event for any kind of button activation?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Which event should I use for any kind of button activation:

- keyboard return
- mouse click
- finger touch

Do I need to define three event handlers or can I do this with just one?

The question aims plain JavaScript without any library use.

And what happens, when W3C invents a new event, which recognizes fart sounds to activate a button? Do I have to add a fourth event handler?

Comment: `click` will do the job for the most part, the browser will handle most of the stuff for you, so keyboard return (enter pressing when the button is on focus) and finger touch both will work on the `click` event listener.

Comment: Question is... You had some issues with a specific code? Otherwise it's all about knowing all the different events and use them when and where needed. `click` will do for most cases, but not for other ones, like i.e. for games. It all depends. `pointer` events are otherwise a better replacement for `mouse` events, etc...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan The question is: does the concept of an unified activation exists, which does not depend on the way the activation is done in particular.

Comment: So what was your issue with the "click" event? If you have a form and you're interested in the form being submitted, than use the "submit" Event on the form itself... Seems like you're having an [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Please read [ask] [edit] with a [mcve] of a specific issue.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what action you want after the event is done.If you have a submit button then use mouse events like:

1. **onclick event** - this activates whenever you click the left button on
   your mouse
2. **oncontextmenu** - this is activated when the right
   button of the mouse is clicked

Comment: I want to recognize the button press action in its most general meaning.

Comment: If you have a "submit" button then it's wiser to set the `"submit"` event on the FormElement itself.